# How do I install GitLabe CE on Bitnami Mattermost AMI Image

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab, bitnami

On Amazon EC2 I have already installed the Bitnami Mattermost Team Edition image from the market place. Now I wish to install GitLab CE on this image. I can launch another EC2 Bitname Gitlabe CE instance. But if I want to install Bitnami Gitlab CE on the same server as Mattermost what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here. Since we don't offer Gitlab CE installers, the best way to have both running in the same server is to launch an EC2 Gitlab CE instance and download/install the latest Bitnami Mattermost CE Stack on that server.

```
wget https://bitnami.com/redirect/to/686136/bitnami-mattermost-5.14.2-0-linux-x64-installer.run
chmod 755 bitnami-mattermost-5.14.2-0-linux-x64-installer.run
sudo ./bitnami-mattermost-5.14.2-0-linux-x64-installer.run
```

You should choose different ports for NGINX since 80 and 443 will be blocked by Gitlab CE installation.

I hope it helps.